# Singly-linked list (insert [list elt]) function

Tags: clojure, insert, singly-linked-list

I am about to lose my mind if I don't find this bug. I implemented a version of a singly-linked list:

```
(ns clojure_fun.core)
(defprotocol MConsP
  (elt [this] "returns elt")
  (cdr [this] "returns cdr")
  (set-elt! [this val] "set elt")
  (set-cdr! [this val] "set cdr")
  )

(deftype MCons [^{:unsynchronized-mutable true} elt
                ^{:unsynchronized-mutable true} cdr]
  MConsP
  (elt [this] elt)
  (cdr [this] cdr)
  (set-elt! [this val] (set! elt val))
  (set-cdr! [this val] (set! cdr val))
  )

(defn mcons [a b] (MCons. a b))
(defn mlist [& xx]
  (if (empty? xx) nil
      (mcons (first xx) (apply mlist (rest xx))))
  )

(defn insert [xx elt]
  (cond (nil? xx) (mcons elt nil)
        (< elt (-> xx cdr elt))
              (set-cdr! xx (mcons elt (cdr xx)))
        :else (insert (cdr xx) elt))
  )

(def x (mlist 1 3 4 5 6))
(insert x 2)
```

When I try to evaluate the last line`(insert x 2)`I get the following error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn, compiling:(clojure_fun/core.clj:1:26)
```

I haven't been so stumped in a long time. Probably because I'm just learning Clojure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
(< elt (-> xx cdr elt))
```

In your local scope, `elt` is a long, and you're trying to apply the `elt` function (now shadowed by the local) to `(cdr xx)`. Just rename the `elt` argument to something else.